# How do I find out in Python whether a gui is available?

Tags: python, tkinter, pytest

For a larger package, I have some tests that create windows in the GUI. These tests cannot run on headless machines, like often in a CI. On these machines, such tests should be skipped with `@pytest.mark.skipif()`, while on the developer's machine they should run.

How can one check this programmatically? It is basically the use of `tkinter`, but I didn't find a proper method there.

Comment: Then check if tkinter is importable?

Comment: tkinter is always importable, even on headless machines.

Comment: Try `import tkinter as tk; tk.Tk().destroy()`. If that throws any errors, than you are on a machine that doesn't support `tkinter`. Also inside `tkinter/__init__.py` you have a line `import _tkinter` which will fail if you are on a machine that doesn't have a gui display.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed in comments:

```py
TEST_NG = False
try:
    import tkinter as tk
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    TEST_NG = True

@pytest.mark.skipif(TEST_NG, reason="Run on headless")
```

Comment: At least on the command line, this does not work. When I switch to a text console on my Linux machine, I still can import tkinter, although no GUI is available. The same happens inside the default Ubuntu (18.04) runner on Github actions.

Comment: interesting, I am running CentOS7